# What is `operator.__inv__` existing for?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, operator-keyword, python-datamodel

What is the difference with `inv` and `invert`?

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.inv is operator.invert
False
>>> operator.__inv__ is operator.__invert__
False
```

I gather that [`__invert__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__invert__) is the hook for the unary ops like `~1` or `(1).__invert__()`.

But what is the other one [`__inv__`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python++__inv__) corresponding to? Or if it's same, why we have another name and a different function added for doing same thing?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.inv), `inv`, `invert`, `__inv__` and `__invert__` are all the same *operator*. Doesn't mean they're the same function.

Comment: As per the docs, [they represent the same operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__inv__). That doesn't mean they have to be the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both represent the same operator. The long spelling was added in Python 2.0, and the short spelling was never removed.

> #### `operator.inv(obj)`
>
> #### `operator.invert(obj)`
>
> #### `operator.__inv__(obj)`
>
> #### `operator.__invert__(obj)`
>
> Return the bitwise inverse of the number *obj*.
>   This is equivalent to `~obj`.
>
> *New in version 2.0:* The names `invert()` and `__invert__()`.

Source: [Python 2 `operator` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__inv__).

These are implemented as different objects because their representation reflects the name. Note that the corresponding dunder and regular names do share the same representation and object.

```
>>> operator.__inv__
<built-in function inv>
>>> operator.__invert__
<built-in function invert>
>>> operator.__inv__ is operator.inv
True
>>> operator.__invert__ is operator.invert
True
```

Historically, both names were equally viable - the [Python 1 `operator` module](https://docs.python.org/release/1.6/lib/module-operator.html) used the `inv`/`__inv__` name, whereas the [Python 1 data model](https://docs.python.org/release/1.6/ref/numeric-types.html) used the special method `__invert__` name.

Comment: OK but this is not really answering my questions. Why is `__inv__` there at all when it's not corresponding to any magic method? And if they're same, then why they have different implementations instead of just being name aliases?

Comment: It answers "what is the other one ``__inv__`` corresponding to" and "why we have another name ". Give me a second for the last one.

Comment: @XÆA-13 Here you are.

Comment: I don't think the name argument is too convincing because e.g. `IOError.__name__` is "OSError"

Comment: Pardon? That's a technical fact, not an argument. ``IOError`` is represented as ``<class 'OSError'>``. The operators were chosen to be represented differently, the errors not. Requiring a separate implementation or not directly follows from this choice.

Comment: I meant it's not that important for the `__name__` attribute to correspond exactly with the name an object is bound to. Why should there be two different implementations of the same function sitting around in memory? Did some hook `__inv__` existed in older version of Python perhaps? They don't just add e.g. `__neg__` and `__negative__` for extra convenience.

Comment: @XÆA-13 Whether this distinction is important or not is a matter of opinion; there is no point arguing on that level. I've added some historical sources on *both* ``__inv__`` and ``__invert__`` existing in different parts of the documented API prior (unlike, say, ``__neg__`` and ``__negative__``); there would have been no advantage in removing one of them, only break of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Alright, that 1.x had `__inv__` _only_ in operator though the datamodel only ever had `__invert__` is telling. I guess it was just a simple mistake in the first place, then the full name was added for consistency's sake, but the original mistake remains with Python to this day.